# Find index locations by regex pattern and replace them with a list of indexes in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, immutability

I have strings in this format:
`object[i].base.base_x[i]` and I get lists like `List(0,1)`.
I want to use regular expressions in scala to find the match `[i]` in the given string and replace the first occurance with 0 and the second with 1. Hence getting something like `object[0].base.base_x[1]`.

I have the following code:

```
val stringWithoutIndex = "object[i].base.base_x[i]"     // basically this string is generated dynamically
val indexReplacePattern = raw"\[i\]".r
val indexValues = List(0,1)     // list generated dynamically

if(indexValues.nonEmpty){ 
    indexValues.map(row => {
       indexReplacePattern.replaceFirstIn(stringWithoutIndex ,  "[" + row + "]")
     }) 
else stringWithoutIndex
```

Since String is immutable, I cannot update `stringWithoutIndex` resulting into an output like `List("object[0].base.base_x[i]", "object[1].base.base_x[i]")`.

I tried looking into StringBuilder but I am not sure how to update it. Also, is there a better way to do this? Suggestions other than regex are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldloop through the integers in `indexValues` using foldLeft and pass the string `stringWithoutIndex` as the start value.

Then use `replaceFirst` to replace the first match with the current value of indexValues.

If you want to use a regex, you might use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=])` and a positive lookbehind `(?<=\[)` to assert the `i` is between opening and square brackets.

```
(?<=\[)i(?=])
```

For example:

```
val strRegex = """(?<=\[)i(?=])"""
val res = indexValues.foldLeft(stringWithoutIndex) { (s, row) =>
  s.replaceFirst(strRegex, row.toString)
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LRWNrE/1) | [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/8VALum)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
scala> val str = "object[i].base.base_x[i]" 
str: String = object[i].base.base_x[i]

scala> str.replace('i', '0').replace("base_x[0]", "base_x[1]")
res0: String = object[0].base.base_x[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for foldLeft. No need for the `if (indexValues.nonEmpty)` check.

```
indexValues.foldLeft(stringWithoutIndex) { (s, row) =>
  indexReplacePattern.replaceFirstIn(s, "[" + row + "]")
}
```